# Sqlplus parameters

Tags: sql, sqlplus

everyone!
I want to know what this line does:

```
sqlplus -s /nolog <<EOF
```

Any ideas? 
Thanks for the help!

Comment: I take it that `EOF` is a [heredoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document) and not a file?

Comment: Yeah. This line is executed in Unix shell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the information that you provided in the comments:

```
sqlplus -s /nolog <<EOF
```

Fires up an instance of `sqlplus` with silent mode enabled (which, I believe, doesn't send out **any** output to the console screen), and without a login explicitly provided (hence the `/nolog`), and it's taking input from the string contained in the `EOF` heredoc (which probably contains login credentials).

[Here](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL%2aPlus_FAQ) is a quick overview of Oracle's documentation on `sqlplus`.

Answer (score 5):

[From HERE](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/sqlplus/options.html):

`-s` The silent option: it suppreses the output of the SQL*Plus banner, the command prompt and the echoing of commands.

`/nolog` Starts SQL*Plus but does not log on (connect) a user/session.

---

So it seems that starts SQL*PLUS without logging on a user/session (nolog option) and don't display info (silent option).

Answer (score 3):

The full excerpt should probably be:

```
sqlplus -s /nolog << ABCDE

CONNECT user/pwd@database
-- DO SQL AND PLSQL STUFF
EXIT

ABCDE
```

Which is similar to running `sqlplus -s user/pwd@database @script.sql` where `script.sql` contains the sql, plsql stuff and the exit command. The `<<` syntax is shell operator for heredoc, which means all following lines are variable-expanded if ${variables} are found, and the first line beginning with `ABCDE` (at the very beginning of the line, no spaces, no tabs) ends the input.